# How to do remote debugging of tests?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I pass jvm debug flags to sbt on start

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9003
```

and see `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9003` on startup.

I use remote debug config in IntelliJ IDEA and it always reports it's connected - `Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:9003', transport: 'socket'`.

I can debug via IntelliJ the main source code but I cannot successfully debug my ScalaTest unit tests. Why?

Comment: Are the tests perhaps executed in `fork := true` mode? Do `show test:fork` and attach the output to the question. See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html.

Comment: show test:fork
     [info] false

Comment: I still never got this to function but I was able to accomplish this all within intellij. I ran SBT console inside , then attached the debugger, and then ran my test. What confuses me is that in the setup described above I can attach remote debugger to non test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is as easy as using these settings:

```
fork in Test := true
javaOptions in Test := Seq("-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9003
")
```

Beware that the JVM is suspended until I connect a debugger, so that we have enough time to connect a debugger.
A breakpoint must be set before connecting.